# Nested html formBuilder with Laravel

Tags: laravel, formbuilder

cart.blade.php

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        @if(Cart::isEmpty())
            <b>The card is empty</b> <a href="/products">Shopping now</a>
        @else
            <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>item id</th>
                        ....
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {!! Form::open(["url"=>"/pay"]) !!}
                    <?php $i = 0; $totalCart_price = 0; ?>
                    @foreach($cart_total_items as $item)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $item['id'] }}</td>
                            ....
                            <td>
                                {!! Form::open(["url"=>"/my-cart/".$item['id'], "method"=>"DELETE", "style"=>"display: inline"]) !!}
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" aria-label="Left Align">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    </button>
                                {!! Form::close() !!}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php $i++; $totalCart_price += Cart::get($item['id'])->getPriceSum(); ?>
                    @endforeach         
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <b>Total price: ${{ $totalCart_price }} {{ Form::hidden("total_price", $totalCart_price) }}</b>
            <br><br>
            {!! Form::submit('check out (paypal)', ["class"=>"btn btn-primary"]) !!}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
            <a href="/my-cart/clear" class="btn btn-danger">Clear cart</a>
        @endif
    </div>
@stop
```

**Issue:** I can delete any item, but during click check out nothing happens, but when I remove `clear item form`, check out run successfully.

I want to run two operations, How Can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have several forms in a page but they should not be nested.
As given in [html5 working draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element):

> 4.10.3 The form element
>
> Content model:
>
> Flow content, but with no form element descendants.

As far as I know form is just the html tags which can be used to send a group(array) of data at once to the server.
In your case your best bet would be to use the ajax query.(though it would make our page javascript dependent)
Or, as I observed you can just seperate the two form like below:

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        @if(Cart::isEmpty())
            <b>The card is empty</b> <a href="/products">Shopping now</a>
        @else
            <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>item id</th>
                        ....
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <<!-- Remove the Form tag from here and insert it below -->>
                    <?php $i = 0; $totalCart_price = 0; ?>
                    @foreach($cart_total_items as $item)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $item['id'] }}</td>
                            ....
                            <td>
                                {!! Form::open(["url"=>"/my-cart/".$item['id'], "method"=>"DELETE", "style"=>"display: inline"]) !!}
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" aria-label="Left Align">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    </button>
                                {!! Form::close() !!}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php $i++; $totalCart_price += Cart::get($item['id'])->getPriceSum(); ?>
                    @endforeach         
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <<!-- Remove the Form tag from above and insert it below -->>
            {!! Form::open(["url"=>"/pay"]) !!}
            <b>Total price: ${{ $totalCart_price }} {{ Form::hidden("total_price", $totalCart_price) }}</b>
            <br><br>
            {!! Form::submit('check out (paypal)', ["class"=>"btn btn-primary"]) !!}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
            <a href="/my-cart/clear" class="btn btn-danger">Clear cart</a>
        @endif
    </div>
@stop
```

Comment: Use AJAX great idea, but there is no way to make overlap between the two operations?

Comment: No. But you can check my answer. I think you can achieve what you want without overlapping the forms.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. Answer was based on what I observed in your code. I have separated two forms without losing the functionality you wanted to achieve.